# How to make an HTTP get() on a local json file using rxjs?

Tags: json, ionic-framework, rxjs, http-get

I am trying to make a request to my local JSON file using Ionic typescript, and retrieve all of the game objects in my JSON file. Here is what I have so far:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Game } from "../../models/Game";

import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

/*
  Generated class for the GamesProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class GamesProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getGames(): Observable<Array<Game>> {

      return this.http.get('/assets/games.json').pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res.json().games),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  public handleError(error: any) {
      // log error
      // could be something more sofisticated
      let errorMsg = error.message || `Yikes! There was a problem with our hyperdrive device and we couldn't retrieve your data!`
      console.error(errorMsg);

      // throw an application level error
      return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
  }
}
```

I am getting a result that looks like this when I call the getGames() function:

```
operator
    :CatchOperator {caught: Observable, selector: ƒ}
    source
    :Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
    _isScalar
    :false
    __proto__
    :Object
```

What I am expecting is an Observable Array of Game objects.

Game.ts:

```
export class Game {
    gameid: number
    genres: string
    images: string
    name: string
    developer: string
    publisher: string
    date: string
    description: string
    players: number
}
```

This is what my JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "games":[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "name": "007: GoldenEye",
    "genres": "Action/First-Person Shooter",
    "date": "25-Aug-97",
    "images": "007: GoldenEye.png",
    "developer": "Rare",
    "publisher": "Nintendo",
    "description": "A video game released for the Nintendo 64.",
    "players": 4
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "name": "007: The World Is Not Enough",
    "genres": "Action/First-Person Shooter",
    "date": "1-Nov-00",
    "images": "007: The World Is Not Enough.png",
    "developer": "Eurocom",
    "publisher": "Electronic Arts",
    "description": "A video game released for the Nintendo 64.",
    "players": 4
  },
...
...
...
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use HttpClient you shouldn't use json();
The get() method on HttpClient makes accessing this data straightforward:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('/assets/games.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.games = data.games;
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
    })
}
```

and then you can use:

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games">{{game | json}}</div>
```

Comment: In the *ngFor,  {{ game | json }} seems like an odd way to access the object. How would you access individual properties in this way, such as game.publisher?

Comment: It is just for debugging. You can use {{game.publisher}}

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of the pipe you need map (and just get rid of pipe)

```
return this.http.get('/assets/games.json').map(
(res: Response) => res.json().games).catch(this.handleError);
```

Check the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http you could also do it with a subscribe

Comment: I will try this and get back to you/answer. Do you know the advantage of subscribe v.s. map?

Answer (score 1):

if your Game class change to

```
export class Game {
    id: number
    genres: string
    images: string
    name: string
    developer: string
    publisher: string
    date: string
    description: string
    players: number
}
```

you can cast output of http.get to your Games class:

```
return this.http.get('/assets/games.json').map(
(res: Response) => <Game>res.json().games).catch(this.handleError);
```

for handling error can use this method

```
protected handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log(error.message || error);
    const response = 'some error occurred!';
    return Observable.of(response);
  }
```

Comment: Tells me that "map" does not exist on object "Observable<Object>"

Comment: How should my imports look? I think it's all messed up.